# How to make a bootable MBR USB in Ubuntu?

Tags: usb, mbr, rufus

I used Rufus in windows to make MBR bootable USB but can't find a Rufus equivalent in Ubuntu

Comment: Do you mean to ask how to create installation media for Ubuntu, using Ubuntu?  Are you aware of balena etcher? It's cross platform and significantly easier to use than Rufus. And it's open source

Comment: You don't need Rufus nor any 3rd party software tool to make a bootable USB drive either from running Win10 or Linux.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Live Ubuntu USB doesnt works on newer systems](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1266222/live-ubuntu-usb-doesnt-works-on-newer-systems)

Comment: @Nmath, Rufus **is** fully Open Source: https://github.com/pbatard/rufus. It's GPLv3.

Comment: **Gnome-Disks** will restore an Ubuntu ISO to USB, (select the disk and click the three lines upper right and then select restore). This creates an ISO9660 partition in MBR. **mkusb** will do the same using the "Live Only" option, as will the **Startup Disk Creator** that comes with Ubuntu. These are all fully Open Source Live USB creators.